# Navigating from an activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to navigate from one activity to another `fragment` through back button?
Please if you know answer, help me. I am new to Android.

Comment: `your question is unclear` and also read this **[ask]**

Comment: Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Your question does not provide and coding effort.

Comment: Use onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use from switching from Fragment to Activity-:

Implement this code on BackPressed-:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

     YourFragment mapFragment = new YourFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.landlord_apartment, mapFragment, mapFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }
```

While moving from Fragment to Activity-:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity,YourActivity.Class));
```

and while moving from activity to Fragment-:

```
YourFragment mapFragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.landlord_apartment, mapFragment, mapFragment.getTag()).commit();
```